# Trouble with using foreign keys in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am having trouble using foreign keys in mySQL. I can't see anything wrong with code that I have made but when I insert data into the table with the foreign key(company table(userid) it doesn't work. Sorry for being vague..first time asking here.

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
userid INT(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
companyName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userid)
) ENGINE=INNODB;





DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;

CREATE TABLE company 
(
userid int(4) NOT NULL,
companyid INT(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
companyName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
telephone INT(20) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
textbody VARCHAR(1800) NOT NULL,
textbody2 VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (companyid),
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(userid)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here is the INSERT STATEMENT

```
INSERT INTO company (companyName, address, telephone, email, textbody, textbody2)VALUES 
('blaaah', 'Ireland', '12345', 'emailAddress', 'randomtext', 'morerandomtext');
```

Here is the error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint     fails(`users`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `    users` (`userid`))
```

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not an acceptable error description.

Comment: Show the `insert` and error statements.

Comment: Where is the error ! as the code is error Free!

Comment: You are not inserting a value for `userid` into the company table - which means you are inserting `NULL`. But MySQL tries to be clever and will silently convert the `NULL` to `0` - and then it fails there is no user with `userid = 0`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4edfa/1  You need to supply a valid (existing) value for the `userid` column when you do the insert.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert a row with a particular `userid` value into your `company` table until you've inserted a row with that same value into your `users` table. That's what the FK constraint enforces.

The `INSERT INTO company` statement you show in your question does not specify the value of `userid`. If you're using foreign key constraints, you must specify that value, and it must be one of the values that's present in your `users` table.

How do you come up with a valid `userid` value?  That's hard to answer precisely without understanding your business logic: why must each `company` row necessarily refer to exactly one `users` row?

One way to solve the problem is to `INSERT` the `company` row immediately (immediately! with no intervening `INSERT` statements!) after you `INSERT` the `users` row. In this case the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will contain the appropriate autoincremented value.

```
INSERT INTO users
       (username, email, password, company, address)
VALUES ('mickey', 'mickey@disney.com', 'ILuvMinnie', 'Walt Disney', 'Burbank');

INSERT INTO company 
       (userid, 
        companyName, address, telephone, 
        email, textbody, textbody2)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),   /* from the previous insert */
       'Walt Disney', 'Burbank, CA', '203 555 1212',
       'info@disney.com', 'The Happiest Place on Earth.', 'morerandomtext');
```

Comment: I have multiple users in the user table with unique userid's so that's not the problem.

Comment: @user3375184 Yes, it is the problem, because you've specified that company.userid may not be null, and the foreign key further enforces this constraint.

Comment: How would I go about inserting the userid into the company table so if it is auto incremented in the users table?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c9bc/1)

I use number format for telephone and last_insert_id() in my insert statement.

```
insert into users (username, email, password, companyName, address) 
values ('test', 'test@test.com', 'ghghb', 'test corp', 'test');

insert into company (userid, companyName, address, telephone, email, textbody, textbody2) 
values (last_insert_id(), 'test','test', 123456, 'test@test.com', 'test', 'test');
```

Please check your constrait statement for company table and [check this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

I think you don't add userId to INSERT statement when insert new row to company. But you should add one existed userId.

**Based on comments:**

If you want to insert new company rows without userId, please define table structrure like as:

```
CREATE TABLE company 
(
userid int(4),
companyid INT(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
companyName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
telephone INT(20) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
textbody VARCHAR(1800) NOT NULL,
textbody2 VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (companyid),

) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

In this case I don't define [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_foreign_key_constraint). You can insert with or without userId new company rows.

Comment: I tried it there and when I insert into the company table I got this error    #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You should use `last_insert_id()` rather than an error-prone subquery like that.

Comment: The insert statement works but only if there is one row in the users table.

Comment: Yes, That is correct functionality. If you want to insert company rows without userId, please don't use this foreign key.

Comment: I tried the updated code and I got this error "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`users`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`))"

Comment: Sorry, I mean don't use foreign key in table structure. I updated my answer.

Comment: But I need to use foreign keys to tie everything together.

Comment: I think you need to add minimum one userId to company insert statement. If userId is not null and need containt id reference to another table why you don't add this id in your insert statement?